# Visual Studio Team Services Reporting

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

As I understand it there is currently no reporting available on Visual Studio Team Services however looking at the source control history it shows the changeset history.  Can additional columns be added here like number of changes, etc. so we can try and use this to understand the history of changes for our source control?

An even better solution would be to get real reporting from visual studio Team Services.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, there are is not a comparable reporting set of capabilities in Visual Studio Team Services that Team Foundation Server on-premises currently has.  The data all exists though in the Visual Studio Team Services account and there many ways of getting to that data:

1. [Work Item Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306.aspx)
2. [Work Item Charts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn407521.aspx)
3. [REST APIs in Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/explore/explore-vso-vsi)
4. [Team Foundation Server SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx) (making calls against Visual Studio Team Services)

I imagine for your particular scenario, you'll want to use either option #3 or option #4 for querying version control information.

**Update**:  We are currently working on an Analytics Service for Visual Studio Team Services data that will work with multiple reporting platforms like PowerBI and many others.

Comment: Thanks very much, already have option 4 up and running, very easy to use.

Comment: We're doing some advanced reporting using SSRS directly against the TFS data warehouse (on premise, TFS 2015).  Is there anyway to migrate these reports to VSTS?  Can we get access to the TFS data warehouse underneath team services?

Comment: @ghawkes unfortunately there actually isn't a SQL Services Analysis Services warehouse in VSTS for each account.  We are going a different direction by building an analytics service where you can connect to from many reporting platforms including PowerBI.